# Can't use stackexchange open id on masterbranch.com

Tags: support, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I'm trying to use my newly created stackexchange open id on:

https://www.masterbranch.com/login.developer

But when I try to login I **always** get prompted for my user and password on the stackexchange site ( even if I was already logged in )

This message appears

[image: this appears]

And I can't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they're borking discovery.

Try using a vanity id (which were added to work around this particular, somewhat common, relying party bug).

When logged into [OpenID.SE](https://openid.stackexchange.com/), go to https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/edit and pick some short unique name for the second field (the overlay is "john.smith (optional)"; I use `kevin.montrose`, for example).

After saving, put `https://openid.stackexchange.com/{your-vanity-id}` into the login form at masterbranch; that should bypass discovery completely.

Comment: It worked, thanks: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9urW.png

Comment: I wonder why do they want the email I use on SO? How can they know that's not my email? http://i.stack.imgur.com/iyzpW.png